# Echarts updating series MarkLine without refresh whole chart

Tags: javascript, html, echarts

I have a huge dataset that needs to be rendered in a scatter plot. I am using Vue.js with vue-charts. The problem I am facing is that when I try to update any series (even adding a new one), the whole chart is refreshed with a huge impact on performance.

Here is a codepen where I reproduce the problem:

https://codepen.io/boosterafk/pen/gOaNazR.

```js
let seriesData = [];
let xAxisData = [];
let yAxisData = ['0','1'];
for(let i = 0; i < 1800; i++){
  xAxisData.push(i);
  for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    seriesData.push([i,j, .4])
  }
}

var container = document.getElementById('main');
var chart = echarts.init(container);
chart.setOption({
  xAxis: {
    data: xAxisData,
  },
  yAxis: {
    data: yAxisData,
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'scatter',
    data: seriesData,
    markLine: {
       data: [ { name: 0, 
               xAxis: 10, 
               label: { 
                 formatter: 0,
                 position: 0,
               }, 
               }, ],
    },
  }],
});

index =10;
window.setInterval(function(){
  chart.setOption({
  series: [{
    markLine: {
       data: [ { name: index, 
               xAxis: index, 
               label: { 
                 position: index,
               }, 
               }, ],
    },
  }],
});
  index+=10;
}, 1000);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.7.0/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

How to fix this problem? What is wrong?

Comment: Could you explain how you check performance and what metrics you see? I have some hypotheses but for check it need reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SergeyFedorov the performance is measured in the time spent during the animation rendering. In my application I have 2 canvas, when I update the chart as I do in this example, I see that everything in the other canvas freeze for a X ms (duration of the animation). I suppose that is because I am dealing with thousands of objects, and that animation is costing a lot. Maybe my question wasn't clear, but what I am trying to do is avoiding the animations on the series data points and just animate the movement of the lineMarker (vertical line) and not of the whole chart as it is now

Comment: Ps: at this point I do not really care even about the animation of the markerLine. I would simply love to not to see that animation Everytime I call `setOption`, just to see if it's getting better. Any idea on how to fix the codePen to remove that animation?

Comment: Try to set `large: true` for series, it will disabled animation and realtime style changes but you'll get some boost.

Comment: Also you can change `largeThreshold` https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.large

Comment: @SergeyFedorov I tried playing with large, and it actually works until you need to have "custom" symbolSize functions. I will try to update the codepen as soon as it gets back online, but if I remove the "large" then symbolSize starts working but animation appears too